# Converting Chart.js canvas chart to image using .toDataUrl() results in blank image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I am using Chart.js. I am trying to convert the chart to an image by getting a base 64 string. The tutorial (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) devotes an entire 1 line on the topic:

> The canvas element also allows for saving the contents as a base 64
>   string, allowing saving the chart as an image.

A `canvas` element has the method of `toDataURL`, which returns a base64 string of the image. However, when I do that, the image it renders is just a transparent rectangle with the dimensions of the chart, and it does not include the chart contents.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSgV7/

The "images" in the fiddle are styled with a black border, so you can see where they are supposed to be, since they seem to just be a big transparent block.

Has anyone successfully converted a Chart.js chart to an image?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhgM8gfBzFQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The chart seem to be async so you will probably need to provide a callback when the animation has finished or else the canvas will be empty.

```
var options = {
    bezierCurve : false,
    onAnimationComplete: done  /// calls function done() {} at end
};
```

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks! They should quote you in the `charts.js` documentation.

Comment: I'm trying to use this exactly but i'm getting a transparent image. The fiddle in this post also has a transparent image

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding updating the image src inside the `onAnimationComplete` callback

Comment: "*The fiddle doesn't work*". Its not supposed to work, it's demonstrating the problem I was having.

Comment: @KoU_warch *I was able to fix it by adding updating the image src inside the onAnimationComplete callback* -- how did you manage that?

Answer (score 32):

Chart.JS API has changed since this was posted and older examples did not seem to be working for me.
here is an updated fiddle that works on the newer versions

HTML:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    <img id="url" />
</body>
```

JS:

```
function done(){
  alert("haha");
  var url=myLine.toBase64Image();
  document.getElementById("url").src=url;
}

var options = {
  bezierCurve : false,
  animation: {
    onComplete: done
  }
};

var myLine = new 
   Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
     {
        data:lineChartData,
        type:"line",
        options:options
      }
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KSgV7/585/

Comment: This work very well ! Thanks - but the <img> tag is missing in your explanation (not in the hyperlink) and I would find your explanation more complete if you add this <img> tag.

Comment: I am happy to fix it but did not get what you are referring two?

Comment: when you write document.getElementById("url").src=url; you reference a html widget with "url" id but I don't see any definition of this element in your post and in any other previous posts. This element is described in the included link but not in your post. I propose that you add this element before Javascript code.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! You helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 11):

First convert your Chart.js canvas to base64 string.

`var url_base64 = document.getElementById('myChart').toDataURL('image/png');`

Set it as a href attribute for anchor tag.

`link.href = url_base64;`

`<a id='link' download='filename.png'>Save as Image</a>`

Answer (score 4):

You should use the Chartjs API function `toBase64Image()` instead and call it after the animation is complete. Therefore:

```
var pieChart, URI;

var options = {
    animation : {
        onComplete : function(){    
            URI = pieChart.toBase64Image();
        }
    }
};

var content = {
    type: 'pie', //whatever, not relevant for this example
    data: {
        datasets: dataset //whatever, not relevant for this example
    },
    options: options        
};    

pieChart = new Chart(pieChart, content);
```

### Example

You can check this example and run it

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Standing costs', 'Running costs'], // responsible for how many bars are gonna show on the chart
      // create 12 datasets, since we have 12 items
      // data[0] = labels[0] (data for first bar - 'Standing costs') | data[1] = labels[1] (data for second bar - 'Running costs')
      // put 0, if there is no data for the particular bar
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Washing and cleaning',
         data: [0, 8],
         backgroundColor: '#22aa99'
      }, {
         label: 'Traffic tickets',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#994499'
      }, {
         label: 'Tolls',
         data: [0, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#316395'
      }, {
         label: 'Parking',
         data: [5, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#b82e2e'
      }, {
         label: 'Car tax',
         data: [0, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#66aa00'
      }, {
         label: 'Repairs and improvements',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#dd4477'
      }, {
         label: 'Maintenance',
         data: [6, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#0099c6'
      }, {
         label: 'Inspection',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#990099'
      }, {
         label: 'Loan interest',
         data: [0, 3],
         backgroundColor: '#109618'
      }, {
         label: 'Depreciation of the vehicle',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#109618'
      }, {
         label: 'Fuel',
         data: [0, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#dc3912'
      }, {
         label: 'Insurance and Breakdown cover',
         data: [4, 0],
         backgroundColor: '#3366cc'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      legend: {
         position: 'right' // place legend on the right side of chart
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            stacked: true // this should be set to make the bars stacked
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            stacked: true // this also..
         }]
      },
      animation : {
         onComplete : done
      }      
   }
});

function done(){
    alert(chart.toBase64Image());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" width="700"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access `afterRender` hook by using `plugins`.

And [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) are all the plugin api available.

In html file:

```html
<html>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  <div id="imgWrap"></div>
</html>
```

In js file:

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  ...,
  plugins: [{
    afterRender: function () {
      // Do anything you want
      renderIntoImage()
    },
  }],
  ...,
});

const renderIntoImage = () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart')
  const imgWrap = document.getElementById('imgWrap')
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL()
  imgWrap.appendChild(img)
  canvas.style.display = 'none'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the toBase64Image() method setting animation: false

```
var options = {
    bezierCurve : false,
    animation: false
};
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSgV7/34/)

Answer (score 0):

@EH_warch
You need to use the Complete callback to generate your base64:

```
onAnimationComplete: function(){
    console.log(this.toBase64Image())
}
```

If you see a white image, it means you called the toBase64Image before it finished rendering.