# Convert Chart (inline chart using dc.js) Canvas to PNG using html2canvas js library

Tags: javascript, linechart, dc.js, html2canvas

[image]

I am using html2canvas library version 0.5.0-beta3 to convert dc.js line chart to png image. but the     image looks as shown in attached Image. Is there any solution to remove black fill in line chart image. please suggest any better library to achieve the same.

code we are trying is

```
html2canvas($("#dashboard-image"), {
                background :'#FFFFFF ',
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    // restore the old offscreen position

                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

}
}

Comment: update chart css and try.

Comment: we tried with css but not working.

Comment: Paste your html code here

Comment: We are getting issue when we are converting to chart to png else the chart is coming properly

Comment: **referance ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206038/convert-charts-js-canvas-chart-to-image-using-todataurl-results-in-blank-imag

Comment: we have issues in html2canvas library can you suggest other library to achieve div snapshot as png image.

Comment: It looks like the CSS from `dc.css` is missing - I've heard this is often a problem with extracting/exporting SVG. If you can find a way to inline the styles, or apply them directly to the SVG elements, that will probably help.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your suggestion. Our problem is solved. We Changed the dc library and put this in dc.js.

var path = layersEnter.append('path')
                   .attr('class', 'line')
                   .attr('stroke', colors)
                   .attr("fill", "#FFF");
               if (_dashStyle) {
                   path.attr('stroke-dasharray', _dashStyle);
               }

But we are still not able to resolve blurry labels which are repeating 2 times in the image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TRY this maybe helpful,

```
$('#dashboard-image').html2canvas({
    onrendered : function(canvas) {
      var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  // here is the most important part because if you dont replace you will get a DOM 18 exception.
    }
});
```

OR

```
html2canvas($("#dashboard-image"), {
                background :'#FFFFFF ',
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
}};
```

OR 
 You can use alternative [option](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image#canvas2image)

Comment: i already tried this code, but line chart is not drawing properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug in html2canvas package.
I made this work by doing a small tweak, please add this piece of code before you call html2canvas:

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.c3-chart-line .c3-lines path');
const nodeList2 = document.querySelectorAll('.c3-axis path');
const lineGraphPath = Array.from(nodeList);
const axisPathArray = Array.from(nodeList2);
lineGraphPath.forEach(function(element: HTMLElement){
    if (element.style.fill === '') {
        element.style.fill = 'none';
    }
});
axisPathArray.forEach(function(element: HTMLElement){
if (element.style.fill === '') {
        element.style.fill = 'none';
        element.style.stroke = '#000';
    }
})
```