# Export react js componet to image (png, jpeg)

Tags: reactjs, png

I have a react js component which renders some graphics and I want to export this component to an image (jpeg, png) so that I can export later this image to a xls file.

I found a module repng but I get some errors when importing this error.

Comment: You could show us a bit of your code or at least the errors in order to have something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I used chart.js and used canvas.toDataURL() to geth the img.

[Converting Chart.js canvas chart to image using .toDataUrl() results in blank image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206038/converting-chart-js-canvas-chart-to-image-using-todataurl-results-in-blank-im)