# Download Chart.js graph from view

Tags: chart.js, data-visualization

I have recently started using Chart.js for data visualization. I am able to do the visualization. My client also want that graph to be downloaded with data information. I know I can do it by giving print button from screen and show relevant data. 
But is there a Chart.js feature available which can download this graph as well as the information in actual numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Stack Overflow answer that points out the way to go: Save the underlying canvas data as Base64 encoded string as image.

[Chart.js chart save as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206038/converting-chart-js-canvas-chart-to-image-using-todataurl-results-in-blank-im)