# how to put dynamic graph as image using chart js in image tag while sending email

Tags: php, laravel, email

let's say i have email template & it's contain dynamic image generation

in my email template

```
<td style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;padding:10px 10px 10px 0;">
 <img src="/index.php">
</td>
```

so when someone open email, i just run that index.php code and return base64 images generated by chart js, i don't clueless what is the right way to do that

```
<script src="/plugins/jquery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/30/20/33/heart-700141_960_720.jpg">
  <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  <img id="url" />
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lineChartData = {
      labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
      datasets : [
          {
              fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
              strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
              data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40],
              bezierCurve : false
          }
      ]

  }

  function done(){
    alert("haha");
    var url=myLine.toBase64Image();
      console.log(url);

    document.getElementById("url").src=url;
  }
  var options = {
    bezierCurve : false,
    animation: {
      onComplete: done
    }
  };


  var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),{
      data:lineChartData,
    type:"line",
    options:options
  });
</script>
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

so how can i achive base64 image in return ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Chart.js canvas chart to image using .toDataUrl() results in blank image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206038/converting-chart-js-canvas-chart-to-image-using-todataurl-results-in-blank-im)

Comment: not dublicate, see it's with laravel, php

Comment: my point is to how to render image of chart js lets say bar chart in email template with dynamic data

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to send an image because email won't execute Javascript.
Setting `Content-type: image/png` on your response won't magically turn the page into image, you need to actually return data with png encoding!

The easiest way to do this is probably with [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/), which is an [open source](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart) web service that I built to render a Chart.js object as an image.

Based on your question, this might be your full Chart.js configuration:

```
{
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"
    ],
    "datasets": [
      {
        "label": "My data",
        "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
        "data": [ 65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40 ],
        "bezierCurve": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Pack it into a URL and send it to the `https://quickchart.io/chart?c=` endpoint.  For example:

[https://quickchart.io/chart?c={ "type": "bar", "data": { "labels": [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July" ], "datasets": [ { "label": "My data", "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)", "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)", "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)", "pointStrokeColor": "#fff", "data": [ 65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40 ], "bezierCurve": false } ] }}](https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7B%0A%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22bar%22%2C%0A%20%20%22data%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22labels%22%3A%20%5B%20%22January%22%2C%20%22February%22%2C%20%22March%22%2C%20%22April%22%2C%20%22May%22%2C%20%22June%22%2C%20%22July%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22datasets%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22My%20data%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22fillColor%22%3A%20%22rgba(220%2C220%2C220%2C0.5)%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22strokeColor%22%3A%20%22rgba(220%2C220%2C220%2C1)%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22pointColor%22%3A%20%22rgba(220%2C220%2C220%2C1)%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22pointStrokeColor%22%3A%20%22%23fff%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22data%22%3A%20%5B%2065%2C%2059%2C%2090%2C%2081%2C%2056%2C%2055%2C%2040%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22bezierCurve%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Don't forget to [URL encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your query parameter (your browser automatically does this when you enter a URL).  Here's an example of how you can do that in PHP:

```
$chart = '{
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"
    ],
    "datasets": [
      {
        "label": "My data",
        "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
        "data": [ 65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40 ],
        "bezierCurve": false
      }
    ]
  }
}';

$encoded = urlencode($chart);
$imageUrl = "https://quickchart.io/chart?c=" . $encoded;

// Embed $imageUrl in your email...
```

Of course, you can dynamically construct `$chart` with your own custom values using [json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858448/converting-object-to-json-and-json-to-object-in-php-library-like-gson-for-java) for example.  But that is beyond the scope of this answer.

The resulting `$imageURL` displays the following:

[image: Chart image]

You can learn more about customizing Chart.js from the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html).

An alternative to this approach is to figure out how to render Chart.js on your own backend, or use a different library that supports server-side chart generation in PHP.

Comment: do we rely on this service ?

Comment: You can rely on quickchart.io or choose to host it yourself because it is open source

Comment: quickchart and chartjs are two different projects right?

Comment: @DavidGarcia That's correct.  Quickchart is a rendering service for Chart.js.