# Charts not showing in wicked pdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts, chart.js, wicked-pdf

When creating the pdf file using wicked pdf in rails no charts are being rendered. I have tried multiple versions of chart.js. Nothing works. Displaying the pdf as html works perfectly. Also, trying to set responsive: false in the chart.js but it did not work as well.

I'm using the following in head tag:

```
 <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "plugin_assets/rtcharts/javascripts/chart.min.js" %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "plugin_assets/rtcharts/javascripts/chart.helper.js" %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "plugin_assets/rtcharts/stylesheets/rtdashboard.css" %>
```

The following is the chart component:

```
  <% charts = controlchart %>
  <div class="rtdashboard grid-container grid-cols-2">
    <% if charts.empty? %>
    <p class="nodata"><%= l(:label_no_data) %></p>
    <% else %>
        <% charts.each do |graph| %>
      <div>
        <%=  render partial: 'rtcharts/bar',
                      formats: [:html],
                      :javascript_delay => 10000,
                      locals: graph %>

       </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

And this is in my controller:

format.pdf  {

```
    render template: 'qmcontrols/show',:type => 'application/pdf', pdf: "#{@project.identifier}_qmcontrol_#{@qmcontrol.id}",
    margin: {left: 15, right:  15 },
    :footer => {:center => "#{@project.name} / #{@location_details[0]['location_company']} / #{@qmcontrol.checkitem_location}", :right => '[page] / [topage]' },:javascript_delay => 5000,show_as_html: true
      }
```

Comment: do the charts work without PDF?

Comment: Yes they are working fine when i show the pdf as html.

Comment: Lots of HTML/JS charting libraries have trouble with `wkhtmltopdf`, because it uses a very old version of webkit. Some details here: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/910 or search the issues for your charting library.

Comment: Hi i am unable to resolve that issue. Should i use some other library for displaying pdf file or change my graph library while using wicked pdf?

Comment: I'd suggest converting the chart to an image first and then embedding it in your PDF.  See https://quickchart.io/ for converting chart.js to image/pdf.

Comment: Thankyou for that. I've done a POC and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i did that by converting the chart to an image first and then embedding it in my PDF. All thanks to @ty

You can see the following url for converting chart.js to image using quickchart.io [Ref. Convert Chart.js data to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352930/how-to-put-dynamic-graph-as-image-using-chart-js-in-image-tag-while-sending-emai)