# Render Chartjs on hidden DIV

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm trying to render many charts using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) on a hidden div, then convert them to images to use in a PDF report.

My problem is: if the chart is not rendered on the DOM, I can't capture it and draw it on a `canvas`. Until the chart is shown, it doesn't render. I've tried to use the methods of `draw` and `render` from `chart.js` but they don't produce the desired results.

Here's my example HTML:

```html
<div style="display: none;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

And my corresponding JavaScript:

```js
var canvas: any = document.getElementById('myChart');
var ctx: any = canvas.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',
    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
          }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
      });

for (var id in Chart.instances) {
    Chart.instances[id].resize();
    Chart.instances[id].draw('1s');
    Chart.instances[id].render('1s');
    console.log(Chart.instances[id].toBase64Image());
}
```

Is there any way to manually render the chart without displaying it, then capture the output as an image?

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular exactly?

Comment: @Dean my bad, wrong tag, it's coded on angular but it doesn't applies, fixing now

Comment: What, specifically, is happening? Are you getting an error? Is the image appearing but garbled? Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206038/converting-chart-js-canvas-chart-to-image-using-todataurl-results-in-blank-im). Also off the top of my head, you could probably render it on a canvass that is visible but not in the viewport.

Comment: @Dean the canvas used to render the chart is always on height and width in 0, and when i try to get the base64 value from the chart is blank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest hack would be to replace:

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

with

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:-9999px;">
```

and it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/FGRibreau/n1cx9d70/2/ :)

PS: If you need to render the chart server-side (e.g. in a batch) in order to then embed it inside PDF reports then you might want to consider dedicated services like [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com).