# How to get the image from graph created using chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am learning about how to create a graph using Chart JS.
And here is my script HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <style type="text/css">
                body{
                        font-family: roboto;
                }
        </style>

        <h2>Example of Chart JS</h2>



        <div style="width: 500px;height: 500px">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>

        <script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["1900", "1950", "1999", "2050"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Australia",
          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
          data: [130,212,252,241]
        }, {
          label: "Asia",
          backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
          data: [348,705,1075,2034]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Population growth (millions)'
      }
    }
});
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: example of graph]

The result of the graph is like picture above.

I want to get the image of the graph to using curl or wget command but it fails because there is no **copy link address** when I click my mouse. Only **Save image As** and **Copy image** in the option like in the picture below:

[image: no copy link address]

So, how to get the image from the graph created using chart JS? Because I want to embed the graph to another site or sent it to the email.
I really really have no idea about this matter.

Comment: Since it's likely a canvas, you could reach into the canvas element and use [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) or [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).  It depends on how you actually want  to use it from the point where it is turned into data.

Comment: @zero298, Thank you for the enlightenment. I will read first.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use `toDataURL` or the built-in Chart.js function `toBase64Image`.  The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206038/converting-chart-js-canvas-chart-to-image-using-todataurl-results-in-blank-im) pretty much cover how to do that.  This may be enough, especially if your use case is entirely within the browser.

The downside is that you can't script this easily with wget or curl, as you mentioned.

A solution to this problem is to use a chart rendering service like [QuickChart](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart), which is an open source project I built that renders Chart.js graphs to image.

Take your chart config and stuff it into the API URL (this uses a public endpoint, but you can host it yourself too):

[https://quickchart.io/chart?c={ type: 'bar', data: { labels: ["1900", "1950", "1999", "2050"], datasets: [ { label: "Australia", backgroundColor: "#3e95cd", data: [130,212,252,241] }, { label: "Asia", backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2", data: [348,705,1075,2034] } ] }, options: { title: { display: true, text: 'Population growth (millions)' } }}](https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%221900%22%2C%20%221950%22%2C%20%221999%22%2C%20%222050%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%22Australia%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%22%233e95cd%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B130%2C212%2C252%2C241%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%22Asia%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%22%238e5ea2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B348%2C705%2C1075%2C2034%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%27Population%20growth%20(millions)%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

By default, this URL produces the following PNG image:

[image: Chart.js rendered image]

The QuickChart/Chart.js [sandbox](https://quickchart.io/sandbox/) is a good way to test how your Chart.js config renders to an image.

You can use curl or wget to fetch the URL-encoded chart directly.  The URL is a mouthful, but it includes your entire chart config (note that it is URL encoded):

```
curl -o mychart.png 'https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%221900%22%2C%20%221950%22%2C%20%221999%22%2C%20%222050%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%22Australia%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%22%233e95cd%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B130%2C212%2C252%2C241%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%22Asia%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%22%238e5ea2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B348%2C705%2C1075%2C2034%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%27Population%20growth%20(millions)%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D'
```